# How do you add keyboard commands to a preexisting javafx scene?

Tags: java, keyboard, javafx, scene

I have been trying to find out how to add keyboard commands to a preexisting javafx scene and i can not seem to find the answer anywhere. Want to have a keyboard method run with a key is pressed. He is what i would like to add the keyboard commands/controls to.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application {
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root =    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Keyboard test app");
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public void key(){

}
}
```

This would really help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a week i figured it out! You need to add a textField and use that to colect keyboard data.
Here is the code:

Main:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@FXML
TextField textBox;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Keyboard test app");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Main Control:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

    public class MainControl implements Initializable {
@FXML
Polygon player_ship;
@FXML
TextField textBox;
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
 textBox.setPromptText("Write here");

    textBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + ke.getText());
        }
    });

    textBox.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            System.out.println("Key Released: " + ke.getText());
    if(ke.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
                System.out.println("Yay!");
    //What you want the computer to do goes here!
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
 The applictation.css can be anything and the main.fxml just has t have a text field everywhere you want keyboard commands is enabled. This code was adapted from: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the documentation carefully, they are full of examples !

As Matt has suggested you must go through the **[Handling JavaFX Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm)**  section carefully.

If you are just looking for an example you must try the **[KeyboardExample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/KeyboardExample.java.htm)**

**N.B.** If you are facing issues trying to implement it, please post the code which you have tried !

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try `KeyCombination` present in JavaFX. Below is a link to `KeyCombination` documentation: 
[KeyCombination](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html)
Simple example is as follows:

```
@FXML
MenuItem menuItem;

menuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.M, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the keyboard is supposed to work.

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Keyboard+Navigation

And I think you might mean something called mnemonics

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/Mnemonic.html